# Macro issues since O365 Migration

Tags: batch-file

Recently a few people have been migrated to Windows 10 and Office 365.

Since then while running this script they receive an error:

> "Too many arguments"

The purpose of the portion of this script is to take 8 output files from a macro and combine them.

Any assistance will be appreciated maybe something I am not seeing here. The mystery increases since there are some users with Windows 10 and Office 365 that do not run into the error using the same macro/script.

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set typeCounter=1
for /L %%i in (1,1,!sessionCount!) do (
    more +1 C:\Macro\Output\Macro_Output_!typeCounter!.csv > C:\Macro\Output\Macro_Output_!typeCounter!_temp.csv
    timeout /t 1 /nobreak > nul
    set /a typeCounter=!typeCounter! + 1
)

type C:\Macro\Output\Macro_Output_1.csv C:\Macro\Output\Macro_Output_2_temp.csv 
C:\Macro\Output\Macro_Output_3_temp.csv C:\Macro\Output\Macro_Output_4_temp.csv 
C:\Macro\Output\Macro_Output_5_temp.csv C:\Macro\Output\Macro_Output_6_temp.csv 
C:\Macro\Output\Macro_Output_7_temp.csv C:\Macro\Output\Macro_Output_8_temp.csv > C:\Macro\Output\!name!_Output_Log_%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-4,4%.csv

set cleanupCounter=1
for /L %%j in (1,1,!sessionCount!) do (
    del C:\Macro\Input\Macro_Input_!cleanupCounter!.csv
    del C:\Macro\Output\Macro_Output_!cleanupCounter!.csv
    del C:\Macro\Output\Macro_Output_!cleanupCounter!_temp.csv
    timeout /t 1 /nobreak > nul
    set /a cleanupCounter=!cleanupCounter! + 1
)
```

Comment: There is no VBScript or macro in the code you posted. Also, which statement exactly is throwing the error?

Comment: Thank you Ansgar, Still learning since I inherited this from the previous owner. This is a snapshot of the batch file that is running the script. This entire section is where it throws the argument error and then closes out. Since I have posted I have done some additional testing and do not believe there is anything wrong with the batch file. So I need to start looking at other possibilities. Possibly .net framework? - so far the only thing I have to go off is users that recently upgraded from win7 to win10 are now running into this.

Comment: Going to assume that `type` command is really one long line.

Comment: I am really baffled why you would make temporary files from a bunch of files and then combine the temporary files.  Just output them directly to the file you want as output in the first place.  There is no need for the variable `typeCounter`.  You can use `%%i` instead. Same goes for the `cleanupCounter`. Just use `%%j`.  I don't see the variable `sessionCount` ever getting assigned a value. Not sure how it knows when to stop.

Comment: This is just a portion of the whole batch file. They are declared as variables earlier on. Some additional information as to why it is being split up. We are taking an initial input file that can contain large numbers of records and splitting them into 8 Rumba sessions. While splitting up the input we also split the output for each session as well. Then when completed it consolidates the 8 sessions.